# Add KML Layer to Google Maps Embed API, NOT Javascript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-embed

I have embedded a Google Map API onto my Google Site, but I am having trouble embedding my KML layer into it. I was wondering if someone could help me with the code.

Here is the code that works for the embedded gadget:

```
<iframe
  width="1200"
  height="900"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=AIzaSyC3UDHvPat9pP5JH19ICl4agjWaNnTiNkI
&center=33.701923, -86.851167
  &zoom=7
  &maptype=roadmap">
</iframe>
```

Here is the code for the KML Layer I am trying to embed:

```
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  driveFileId: "0B4CQLXiFWdl2OVV6STI5b1BLSUE"
});
```

I have tried everything and I keep getting code errors. Any help is really appreciated!

***Reply to answer:

I did look at that page before posting my question and I am not sure how I can use that HTML code within my Google Gadget on my Google Site. I have tried, but it doesn't work. The initial code I put above gets turned into this:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&amp;cht=d&amp;chdp=sites&amp;chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Gadget'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D1199'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Include+gadget+(iframe)%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D1200'%3D897'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D1200'%3D897'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&amp;sig=iWHUUzTOFEKRgAUogMaGWUuybBY" data-igsrc="http://0.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=0&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fembed%2Fv1%2Fview%3Fkey%3DAIzaSyC3UDHvPat9pP5JH19ICl4agjWaNnTiNkI%0A%26center%3D33.701923%2C+-86.851167%0A++%26zoom%3D7%0A++%26maptype%3Droadmap&amp;w=1200&amp;h=900" data-type="ggs-gadget" data-props="height:900;igsrc:http#58//0.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=0&amp;synd=trogedit&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gstatic.com%2Fsites-gadgets%2Fiframe%2Fiframe.xml&amp;up_iframeURL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fmaps%2Fembed%2Fv1%2Fview%3Fkey%3DAIzaSyC3UDHvPat9pP5JH19ICl4agjWaNnTiNkI%0A%26center%3D33.701923%2C+-86.851167%0A++%26zoom%3D7%0A++%26maptype%3Droadmap&amp;w=1200&amp;h=900;mid:0;spec:http#58//www.gstatic.com/sites-gadgets/iframe/iframe.xml;up_iframeURL:https#58//www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=AIzaSyC3UDHvPat9pP5JH19ICl4agjWaNnTiNkI &amp;center=33.701923, -86.851167   &amp;zoom=7   &amp;maptype=roadmap;width:1200;" width="1200" height="900" style="display:block;text-align:left;margin-right:auto;" class="igm">
```

So there is no way to put a KML layer into that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have posted in your question,  you are embedding the map in an iframe, yet trying to add your KML layer to it via script.  These two methods would be incompatible together, since there is no reference to the map object on your page (its in the iframe).

I would recommend taking a look at the kml example on on the google maps website,  which will take you through the process of instantiating the maps object,  adding the KML layer, and then assigning the KML layer to your map object. like so:

```
function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696,-87.624207);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: chicago
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Comment: My reply was too long... Please see my reply in the original question. Thanks!